# Managing problematic formatted international characters in filename

Tags: vba, excel

I have some files in a folder that seems to be formatted in a strange way when accessing them in VBA.

The code below is a simple test. It scans the Excel-files in a folder and simply opens and closing them again (just to test the problem). It works fine even if the filename contains Swedish characters such as å,ä,ö.

```
Sub ScanFiles()
    Dim ExcelFile As String
    Dim WB As Workbook

    ExcelFile = Dir("c:\Somepath\*.xlsx")
    Do While ExcelFile <> ""
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile)
        WB.Close False
    Loop
    ExcelFile = Dir()
End Sub
```

This works fine... *until*... this happens:

- One filename is listed as "Sömething.xlsx". Even if I take a detailed look in the file properties. It *is* really "Sömething.xlsx"!
- But the variable `ExcelFile` stores "So¨mething.xlsx". The `Workbooks.Open` command fails since the file with that name can't be found

It seems that the specific file has been saved in an Apple environment.

Why is this happening and how do I manage it?

Comment: `Dir` doesn't work with file names with Unicode characters. You can use `FileSystemObject`